# How to decompile .mexw64

Tags: c, matlab, mex, decompiler

When I used the mexw64 file, I found that the result was not what I expected, so I wondered if I could decomcompile it into a readable file to see if that part was wrong.

However, I did not find a way to decompile through the Internet.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I believe MATLAB makes a very serious effort into making sure this cannot be done. The absolute easiest route is to find the source code by asking whoever provided the mex file.

Comment: A MEX-file is a standard DLL (in Windows). You can list the binary code as assembly, and attempt to make sense of that, and even modify it. But assembly is hard to write and even harder to read. In particular, as far as I know, there is no way to generate readable higher level language source code from it, and there certainly is no way to retrieve the original source code that it was compiled from. Also, your license might explicitly prohibit you from attempting to reverse-engineer the MEX-file, read your license!

Comment: @AnderBiguri MEX-files are built with a compiler and linker, there is no explicit obfuscation. MATLAB cannot change how the MEX-file is created, because it is the system loader that must be able to read it. It works just like any other .dll or .so or .dylib.

Comment: Fair point @CrisLuengo! You are right! Apparently it is indeed quite hard to decompile C++ and Fortran anyway, so my second point still stands, but you are right in the obfuscation part.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Your second point is 100% correct.

Comment: Thank you all, it doesn't seem like there's a neat way to decompile it into source code, I'll close this question. sorry